# Sign in confirm link best pratice?

Tags: php, authentication, confirmation-email

as by title,  which is the best way to build the sign in email confirm link?

i suppose id_user/23414/pass/md5(user password)

not? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a token and assign it to the user - a guid or something. You shouldn't send the user id or the hashed password.